# Best way to use Farseer/Box2D's DebugDraw in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, box2d

Box2D/Farseer 2D physics has a useful component which draws a simple representation of the physics world using primitives (lines, polygons, fills, colors). Here's an example:

[image]

What's the best way to accomplish this in Unity3D? Is there a simple way to render polygons with fill, lines, points, etc.? If so, I could implement the interface of DebugDraw with Unity's API, but I'm having trouble finding how to implement primitive rendering like this with Unity.

I understand it'll be in 3D space, but I'll just zero-out one axis and use it basically as 2D.

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean actually a **debug** box just displayed in the `SceneView` **not** in the `GameView` you can use [Gizmos.DrawWireCube](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.DrawWireCube.html)

```c#
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    //store original gizmo color
    var color = Gizmos.color; 

    // store original matrix
    var matrix = Gizmos.matrix;

    // set gizmo to local space
    Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

    // Draw a yellow cube at the transform position
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;

    // here set the scale e.g. for a "almost" 2d box simply use a very small z value
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(0.5f, 0.2f, 0.001f));

    // restor matrix
    Gizmos.matrix = matrix;

    // restore color
    Gizmos.color = color;
}
```

you can use `OnDrawGizmosSelected` to show the Gizmo only if the GameObject is selected

[image]

you could also extend this by getting the box size over the inspector

```c#
[SerializeField] private Vector3 _boxScale;
```

and using

```c#
Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, _boxScale);
```